# электроника, гаджеты

Tags: электроника

Здравствуйте, хочу научиться создавать свои умные гаджеты. Помогите с выбором нужной литературы, у кого есть опыт в этом деле, чтобы было побольше конкретики и примеров создания чего-либо.Я новичок в этом деле, поэтому поэтому хотелось бы начать с чего-то простого.

Comment: Ничего не понял...

Comment: прежде чем задавать вопросы, пожалуйста ознакомьтесь с разделом справки [на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Денис, мне нужна литература - книги, пособие для начинающих по программированию плат, микроконтроллеров и прочее, чтобы я мог научиться создавать что-то свое. Я не знаю с чего начать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А что вы планируете делать? Различные платформы обладают совершенно разными возможностями, от совсем простого ESP8266, до Intel Joule, который некоторые старые лэптопы уделывает по всем параметрам.

Comment: свой умный браслет создать

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете начать с покупки набора Аrduino или аналогичного. Данные наборы включают в себя все необходимые вещи что бы начать:

- микроконтроллер
- документацию
- руководство по созданию различных устройств
- дополнительные детали для создания различных устройств описанных в руководстве

Создатели наборов также предоставляют видео руководства и много дополнительной литературы.

На территории России подобные наборы продаются фирмой [Амперка](http://amperka.ru/collection/kits)

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!!

Comment: на какой территории?:)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо. исправил.

Comment: А лучше не начинайте с Arduino, это как с бейсика начинать учить программирование. Вроде просто, но не в ту сторону.